# How to make javascript pagination work in nav tab

Tags: javascript, pagination

**Tab 1**
[image]

**Tab 2**
[image]

I use jQuery simplePagination.js for pagination. The pagination is work on Tab 1 by show 1 data in each page but in Tab 2 it show all the data in 1 page. Supposed in Tab 2 have 2 page. I have attach the image above, to show what I mean it. How to solve this pagination problem on Tab 2 to show only 1 data in 1 page.

```js
updateNumItem();
function updateNumItem() {
        var item = $("#tab1 tbody tr:visible");
        var numItem = item.length;
        var perPage = 1;
        item.slice(perPage).hide();

        $('#pagination-container').pagination({
            items: numItem,
            itemsOnPage: perPage,
            prevText: "&laquo;",
            nextText: "&raquo;",
            onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
                var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
                var showTo = showFrom + perPage;
                item.hide().slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
            }
        });

        var items = $("#tab2 tbody tr:visible");
        var numItems = items.length;
        items.slice(perPage).hide();

        $('#pagination-container1').pagination({
            items: numItems,
            itemsOnPage: perPage,
            prevText: "&laquo;",
            nextText: "&raquo;",
            onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
                var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
                var showTo = showFrom + perPage;
                items.hide().slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplePagination.js/1.4/simplePagination.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplePagination.js/1.4/jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tab">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a href="#tab1" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">TAB1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#tab2" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">TAB2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active py-3" id="tab1">
                <table class="table table-striped" id="data1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Month</th>
                            <th>Year</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Alice Jay</td>
                            <td>January</td>
                            <td>2023</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Park Jay</td>
                            <td>December</td>
                            <td>2023</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Janey Yu</td>
                            <td>March</td>
                            <td>2022</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Alex Lee</td>
                            <td>April</td>
                            <td>2021</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Karl Peter</td>
                            <td>March</td>
                            <td>2021</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Herry Harry</td>
                            <td>January</td>
                            <td>2020</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Wendy Lee</td>
                            <td>January</td>
                            <td>2023</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Rayan Otto</td>
                            <td>January</td>
                            <td>2023</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Ellie Billie</td>
                            <td>January</td>
                            <td>2023</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>George Laire</td>
                            <td>January</td>
                            <td>2023</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tammy Tom</td>
                            <td>August</td>
                            <td>2021</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>John Johnny</td>
                            <td>July</td>
                            <td>2021</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Kenny Daniel</td>
                            <td>June</td>
                            <td>2021</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Leon Frank</td>
                            <td>December</td>
                            <td>2022</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Sam Henry</td>
                            <td>February</td>
                            <td>2022</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div id="pagination-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade py-3" id="tab2">
                <table class="table table-striped" id="data2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Month</th>
                            <th>Year</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jay</td>
                            <td>January</td>
                            <td>2023</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Park</td>
                            <td>December</td>
                            <td>2023</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div id="pagination-container1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

"How to solve this pagination problem on Tab 2 to show only 1 data in 1 page" - the easy way to fix is:

```
<div class="tab-pane active fade py-3" id="tab2">
```

Comment: It still not work. Do you have another solution?